# Modify clock interrupt handler xinu

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, interrupt, xinu

I have an operating systems project due tonight, and needed clarification on a topic. We are working with the operating system XINU. I am trying to change the default OS scheduler to account for some processes being starved. I was directed towards the clkint.S file, which I think is the clock interrupt handler. My question is, how do I know how often it interrupts? How do I set the time to lets say make a function call every 5 seconds? I have looked at the intel x86 manuals, but they have an absurd amount of information to sift through, and I am short on time If someone can point me in the right direction, I'd be grateful.

Here are a couple of files I think necessary:

```
clkint.S:

    /* clkint.s - _clkint */

#include <icu.s>
        .text
count1000:  .word   1000
        .globl  sltop
        .globl  clkint
clkint:
        pushal
        cli
        movb    $EOI,%al
        outb    %al,$OCW1_2

        incl    ctr1000
        subw    $1,count1000
        ja  cl1
        incl    clktime
        movw    $1000,count1000
cl1:
        cmpl    $0,slnonempty   # if no sleeping processes,
        je  clpreem     #   skip to preemption check
        movl    sltop,%eax  # decrement key of first
        decl    (%eax)      #   sleeping process
        jg  clpreem     # must use jg for signed int
        call    wakeup      # if zero, call wakeup
clpreem:    decl    preempt     # decrement preemption counter
        jg  clret       # must use jg for signed int
        call    resched     # if preemption, call resched
clret:                  # return from interrupt
        sti
        popal
        iret
```

clkinit.c:

```c
/* clkinit.c - clkinit */

#include <xinu.h>
#include <interrupt.h>
#include <clock.h>

uint32  clktime;        /* seconds since boot           */
uint32  ctr1000 = 0;        /* milliseconds since boot      */
qid16   sleepq;         /* queue of sleeping processes      */
int32   slnempty;       /* zero if the sleep queue is empty;    */
                /*   non-zero otherwise         */
int32   *sltop;         /* ptr to key in first entry of sleepq  */
                /*   if sleepq is not empty     */
uint32  preempt;        /* preemption counter           */
   
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * clkinit - initialize the clock and sleep queue at startup
 *------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
void    clkinit(void)
{
    uint16  intv;           /* clock rate in KHz        */

    /* Set interrupt vector for clock to invoke clkint */

    set_evec(IRQBASE, (uint32)clkint);

    /* clock rate is 1.190 Mhz; this is 10ms interrupt rate */
    intv = 1190;

    sleepq = newqueue();    /* allocate a queue to hold the delta   */
                /* list of sleeping processes       */
    preempt = QUANTUM;  /* initial time quantum         */

    /* Specify that seepq is initially empty */

    slnonempty = FALSE;

    clktime = 0;        /* start counting seconds       */

    /*  set to: timer 0, 16-bit counter, rate generator mode,
        counter is binary */
    outb(CLKCNTL, 0x34);

    /* must write LSB first, then MSB */
    outb(CLOCK0, (char)intv);
    outb(CLOCK0, intv>>8);
    return;
}
```

clkhandler.c:

```c
/* clkhandler.c - clkhandler */

#include <xinu.h>

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  clkhandler - handle clock interrupt and process preemption events
 *          as well as awakening sleeping processes
 *------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
interrupt clkhandler(void)
{
    clkupdate(CLKCYCS_PER_TICK);

    /* record clock ticks */

    clkticks++;

    /* update global counter for seconds */

    if (clkticks == CLKTICKS_PER_SEC) {
        clktime++;
        clkticks = 0;
    }

    /* If sleep queue is nonempty, decrement first key; when the    */
    /* key reaches zero, awaken a sleeping process          */

    if (nonempty(sleepq) && (--firstkey(sleepq) <= 0)) {
        wakeup();
    }

    /* Check to see if this proc should be preempted */

    if (--preempt <= 0) {
        preempt = QUANTUM;
        resched();
    }
    return;
}
```

I can add all of the starvation functionality on my own, I just need to figure out how to make the clkint.s handler call my function lets say A every 5 seconds...I don't understand how the clock works or the assembly entirely. I am not asking for someone to give me a solution, I just need some guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`intv` is the time slicing granularity (in Khz) for the interrupt timer for scheduling (at least in this code). Every 5 seconds sounds very slow and is likely to make your system barely responsive, try on the order of milliseconds.

To calculate a new interval you need to change this value and do a little math with the frequency. You can probably figure this step out from the calculation done on `intv` to get 10ms.

In x86 the timer value can be established by writing the timer interrupt value in KHz to the port `0x40` using the `outb` assembly instruction. As shown in the code you have to write the least significant byte followed by the most significant (`outb` writes a byte at a time). To enable the timer you write `0x36` to the same port and you must bind an IRQ handler to IRQ0 in order to receive the interrupt. I tried condensing the info for you a bit but this is x86 specific.

Comment: I don't even understand how changing the value of intv would effect anything..it is not used anywhere else as far as I can see. I found a clkhandler.c, can I calculate the time passed and call my function there? I added it above.

Comment: @blackdemon619 That's because it's on a rigid interrupt timing. You can always change the timing by changing the value of the interrupt timer.

Comment: @blackdemon619 If you want to learn a little more I have my own OS written and you can take a look at how I do some of this (again x86 specific) https://github.com/jesus-ramos/not-a-good-os/blob/master/kernel/timer.c

Comment: I see that clktime says seconds since boot in the comments section of the .S file provided. If I check if (clktime % 4 == 0), can I effectively call something every four seconds in the interrupt clkhandler?

Comment: @blackdemon619 Yes, I would not recommend only scheduling every 4 seconds though, you have to remember that USB devices are polling based and if things are long running without interrupt you never get a chance to check device status so your system will seem very unresponsive. Is there a reason you want to do it at 4/5 second granularity? That's a lot of CPU cycles

Comment: Sorry let me clarify. I simply want this specific function to be called every fourth second to check to see if processes are starving. If they are, I will bump their priorities up. I do not want to change anything else related to the clock handler.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26496/discussion-between-blackdemon619-and-jesus-ramos)